# How to pass a field from a view to a Kendo Grid?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I have a Kendo grid whose read function requires a parameter called ID.  If I hard-code the ID, the read command works: it calls the action in the controller and returns the data for the grid.  I can't figure out how to pass it a value from a control on the page.  I've been searching all afternoon and can't find an answer.  Can someone explain how to do this?

Here's my grid with the hard-coded value:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<tblContractPay>()
   .Name("GridContractPay")
   .Columns(columns =>
     {
       columns.Bound(o => o.SchedDate).Title("Date").Visible(true).Format("{0:M/dd/yyyy}");
       columns.Bound(o => o.Amount).Title("Amout").Visible(true).Format("{0:c}");
     })
   .Pageable(x => x.PageSizes(new[] { 10, 25, 50, 100 }).Refresh(true).ButtonCount(5))
   .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
   .WebApi()
   .Read(read => read.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("AppStdApi", new { controller = "WoApi", Action = "GetContractPay", id = "65" })))
   .PageSize(25)
 )
 .AutoBind(true)
)
```

Here is the action in the controller:

```
    public DataSourceResult GetContractPay([ModelBinder(typeof(Koorsen.ModelBinders.DataSourceRequestModelBinder))] DataSourceRequest request, string id)
    {
        var obj = rep.GetContractPayByContract(int.Parse(id)).ToDataSourceResult(request);

        return obj;
    }
```

This works fine.  If, in the read function, I try to pass a javascript function GetContractID instead of the hard-coded value 65, it literally passes "GetContractID" to the controller.

```
.Read(read => read.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("AppStdApi", new { controller = "WoApi", Action = "GetContractPay", id = "GetContractID" })))
```

Here's the code for that javascript function:

```
function GetContractID()
{
    var contractID = $("#CoContractId").val();
    return
    {
        id: contractID
    }
}
```

I've also tried putting $("#CoContractId").val() right in the read function (throws a syntax error)and returning just the contract ID instead of id: contract ID in the javascript (never gets to the controller).

So how do I pass $("#CoContractId").val() as the value for ID instead of a hard-coded value in this statement:

```
.Read(read => read.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("AppStdApi", new { controller = "WoApi", Action = "GetContractPay", id = ??? })))
```

Update

I also tried writing the read command like the code below.  It didn't work.  When the page with grid is hit and when the grid is refreshed, it never hits the controller when I put a breakpoint in it.

```
Read(read => { read.Action("GetContractPay", "WoApi").Data("GetContractID"); })
```

Answer (score 0):

The officially recommended approach is to use an auxiliary function defined via `Read(r => r.Data("..."))`

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/ajax-binding#pass-additional-data-to-action-methods

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work.  It never hits my controller.  Here's my code: Read(read => { read.Action("GetContractPay", "WoApi").Data("GetContractID"); })